# Prove that for a null recurrent or transient DTMC we have $\lim n -> \infty \space P(X_n = i) = 0$ for all $i$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, markov-chains

I think I have to use the dominated convergence theorem somehow in order to switch limits. What I do know is that $\lim n -> \infty \space P_{ij}^n = 0$ for any states $i, j$ within a null recurrent or transient DTMC.

Thus, I want to do $\lim n->\infty \space P(X_n = i) = \lim n \sum{P(X_n = i| X_0 = j) P(X_0 = j)} = \sum \lim n \space P(X_n = i| X_0 = j) P(X_0 = j) = 0$.

However, I don't know what random variable to define so that I get this summation as its expectation.

Comment: A suggestion: write e.g. \lim_{n\to\infty} for $$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$ It would make your post much more legible.

Comment: Hint: for a positive recurrent chain with (unique) stationary distribution $\pi$, for each state $i$ we have
$$
\pi_i = \frac1{\mathbb E[\tau_{ii}]},
$$
where $\tau_{ii}$ is the first return time to state $i$, assuming that the process started in state $i$. Now, for a null recurrent chain we have $\mathbb E[\tau_{ii}]=\infty$, which does not work with the equation above. For a transient chain make use of the fact that with probability one, transient states are visited a finite number of times. You'll need some results relating limiting/stationary distributions as well.